# Testing an Angular Library, both the library components and the example app at the same time

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have created an Angular library using official guidelines and other posts (like [this one](https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5%20from%20@Todd%20Palmer)).

The library is very simple, it contains just one component `component.ts` with its tests in `component.spec.ts`.

Together with the library I have also a sample app, where I show how to use `component.ts`. The sample app is represented by `app.component.ts` which has its own tests in `app.component.spec.ts`.

The scaffolding of my workspace has been created by Angular CLI (v 6.0.8). The structure of the workspace, at least for the files that I suspect are more relevant for my case, is the following

```
workspace
 - projects
   - library-name
     - src
       - lib
         - component.ts
         - component.spec.ts
       - test.ts
     - karma.config.ts
 - src
   - app
     - app.component.ts
     - app.component.spec.ts
   - karma.config.ts
 - angular.json
```

If I run `ng test library-name` only the tests of `component.spec.ts` are run.

If I run `ng test` without specifying the library name, because I want to test both the component and the example app, what happens is the following:

- a browser is opened automatically by karma
- the tests of `app.component.spec.ts` are run and the results are shown on the browser just opened
- if I stop the process with **ctrl+C** a new process start and the tests of `component.spec.ts` are executed (i.e. the interruption of the first test process starts a second test process)
- if I stop again the test with **ctrl+C** then eventually everything stops and I return to the command line

My question is if there is a way to run both the tests of `app.component.spec.ts` and `component.spec.ts` within the same process.

Comment: @Shashank Vivek can you check this : https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/integrate-jest-into-an-angular-application-and-library

Answer (score 7):

I know its an old post which is still unanswered but I looked into it and found the solution.

```
ng test example-ng6-lib-app --no-watch && ng test example-ng6-lib --no-watch
```

where `example-ng6-lib` is the **library** name as per the the attached [article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5%20from%20@Todd%20Palmer) of the question.

Please give it a try